# How do I save my game?

Tags: donkey-kong-land

I was playing Donkey Kong Land for the first time last night and it saved after the first level. I figured it would save after every level, but after I completed the second level and went to the third, it didn't save. I ended up getting a Game Over in level 3, and when I went back to my file, it had just saved when I beat the first level, not the second.

How do I tell the game I want to save? Is that an option, or does it only save every few levels?

I know I can work around this somewhat by abusing the restore point feature on the 3DS Virtual Console games, but I'd like to save the game properly if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have collect all the KONG letters in a level and finish the level in order for the game to save.

> K-O-N-G Letters do not grant an extra life, as they do in other games. Instead, collecting the KONG letters and finishing a level will save the game.

[Wiki Source.](http://donkeykong.wikia.com/wiki/Donkey_Kong_Land)

Here is a little bit of extra information:

> In Donkey Kong Land, the K-O-N-G letters do not grant extra lives and are instead used to save the game. If the player finishes a level with a full set of K-O-N-G letters the game will be saved. In one level in this game, this has an even stranger use for K-O-N-G letters. The player collects the four letters in rapid succession before jumping on an industrial fan. This blows the letters across the level where they can be used as platforms. This is repeated for three sets of K-O-N-G letters; only the fourth and final set can be used for saving the game.

[More Wiki](http://donkeykong.wikia.com/wiki/K-O-N-G_Letters)

Comment: Well, that's delightfully frustrating.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Hehe games aren't what they used to be